# Does anyone know where I can find "proof" that SQL's Fiber mode is barely faster than regular thread mode on Win 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, threads

I remember seeing a PDC presentation on the Windows Kernel regarding Threads vs Fibers and in it Mark R. mentioned that this caused SQL's Thread mode to run almost as fast as Fiber mode, but with added stability.

Does anyone have a link to this? Or similar?

I'll use this as a motivation to push people to 2008R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anybody using Fiber mode for SQL after all these years and I cannot ever recall anyone ever telling me its a good idea. I know the following is rather old, but take a quick peek at this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175385%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

However this article from Linchi gives a more positive spin

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2009/05/04/performance-impact-thread-mode-vs-fiber-mode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Some of the more interesting comments I have found on StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946111/currentthread-processthread-objects/2946266#2946266

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796217/what-is-the-difference-between-a-thread-and-a-fiber